# Timer in Lua without using OS module?

Tags: lua

I would like to implement a timer in Lua without using the `os` library.

I am working on a mod for a game I play, whose game scripts are written in Lua. I would like to implement a timer function, but for security reasons the game does not allow access to the `os` library and its `time` function. Is there still a way, or should I give up?

EDIT: The game's scripting engine is Halley, a lightweight engine written in C++. It appears to be a custom engine built by the developers of the game. https://github.com/amzeratul/halley

EDIT 2: This mod is intended for online multiplayer, so it has to work with the base game Lua scripts, and that means I can't use third party libraries or the OS library (trying to require it will throw an error). After much consideration I have come to believe that it is sadly not possible. Thanks to everyone who gave me comments.

Comment: Please add a tag to your question to specify the game scripting engine (roblox/gta/etc.)

Comment: [`socket.sleep`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#sleep) and [`socket.gettime`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#gettime).

Comment: I have edited the question with details about the game's scripting engine.

Comment: You can regain `os` library by `os = require"os"`

Comment: Often Lua blocks the game loop, so would it even be feasible to block the thread (in any way)? Most often, timing is done using game events (game world events, ui events, input events)

Comment: I should have clarified that this mod is designed for online multiplayer games, so it has to work with the game's native lua scripts. I am unable to require"os" as it throws an error, and similarly am unable to use third-party libraries. 

Originally I thought it might have been possible using coroutines but I now think that it's sadly not possible.  Thanks to everyone who gave me input.